# Spring-Data @Query with Collection params

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Below is my repository method

```
List<Shipment> findByProductCategoriesBetweenQuarter( Set<Category> categories, Quarter from, Quarter to)
```

where Category is an Entity and Quarter is @Embeddable as below

```
class Quarter {
 int year;
 Quarters q; //Enum 
}
```

I would like to create a custom Repository impl with @Query with a below representational query

```
@Query("select s from Shipment s where Category in (categories) and Quarter between (from, to)")
```

Looks like `@Query` works pretty well with primitives, couldn't find an example which could help me implement the case above.

so couple of question here
1. Is it possible at all
2. If possible, requesting some reference.

PS: Cant do QueryDSL now.

Comment: What does Category look like. What columns are in the database?

Answer (score 3):

JPA will store `Enum` ordinal as `int` in the database tables.

So you can do the following.

```
@Query("select s from Shipment s where Category in (categories) and Quarter between (from.ordinal(), to.ordinal())")
```